# How much did Greek mythology vary throughout different regions of Greece?

Tags: greek, history

I have picked this question up from the sample questions in the definition phase of this site. I found this question very interesting.

How different is the mythology across various regions of Greece, and are they connected to each other in some way or the other?

Comment: Books and books have been written on this subject. Short answer: quite a lot, but it's hard to tell, because there was so much connecting them, too. Long answer: I'll need some time to write up a proper response!

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I can wait :)  Can you also suggest some nice books to get started at Greek Mythology [on chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23261/the-pantheon)?

Comment: http://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/1132/62

Comment: @Hamlet Thank you. That's an amazing resource :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regions_of_ancient_Greece) says...

> The regions of ancient Greece were areas identified by the ancient Greeks as geographical sub-divisions of the Hellenic world. These regions are described in the works of ancient historians and geographers, and in the legends and myths of the ancient Greeks.

Then, if you go on, then you get a whole bunch of regions of Greece.

Then, Ctrl+F it and search up "myth" and 4 of them pop up.

1. Stated in the first paragraph.
2. > Acarnania's foundation in Greek mythology was traditionally ascribed to Acarnan, son of Alcmaeon.

Well, that says that the mythology was based off him, and you are GUARANTEED a different account from other people.

3. > The mountains contained many wild beasts, and acquired fame in Greek mythology as the scene of the hunt for the Calydonian Boar.

That means that a whole bunch of Artemis myths would have come from it, but that's just an inference.

4. > Pausanias says that 'Achaean' was the name of those Greeks originally inhabiting the Argolis and Laconia, because they were descended from the sons of the mythical Achaeus, Archander and Architeles.

I don't know about the last two names, but Acheaus was a direct descendent from Promotheus. Maybe all the mythology about Promotheus comes from that place.

What you do, if you want all of them, is go through all of the sites that have anything to do with that, and keep on repeating what I just did, getting your results.