# Could someone tell me about good books about Hawaiian mythology?

Tags: hawaiian

Could someone tell me about good books about Hawaiian mythology?

I've been really interested in it for a long time but I have no idea where to ask for advice or whom to believe.

Comment: [Hawaiian Mythology](https://books.google.com/books/about/Hawaiian_Mythology.html?id=3SuCTOafmR8C&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false), the book, sounds interesting...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good sources to introduce people to mythology?](http://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1132/what-are-good-sources-to-introduce-people-to-mythology)

Comment: Thanks for the book @bleh (although was it really necessary to edit that capital letter? xd), and a couple of sources from that post look interesting, but there's almost nothing specifically about Hawaii and it's all mostly online. I want as many reliable books about that subject and only that one if possible, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentions by @bleh in a comment, [Hawaiian Mythology](http://sacred-texts.com/pac/hm/index.htm) by Martha Warren Beckwith (1940) seems like a good start.

In the [references](http://sacred-texts.com/pac/hm/hm42.htm) section of this book you will find a large amount of books/scholarly articles on polynesian and hawaiian mythology. Among the hawaiian references, some names of scholars pop up frequently: those of Joseph S. Emerson and Nathaniel B. Emerson (sons of a missionary), but also [Mary Kawena Pukui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Kawena_Pukui) and Laura Green.

The page on the website [sacred-texts.com](http://sacred-texts.com/pac/index.htm) on Pacific mythologies contains also several other works, in addition to 'Hawaiian Mythology', by Martha W. Beckwith and by W. D. Westervelt.

The works of these few scholars should already cover a significant portion of the subject, I think.