# Is Homer a good overview, or an encompassing view, of Greek Mythology?

Tags: greek, homer

I read philosophy, and so often is Homer referenced as giving extraordinary accounts of Greek Mythology, and it seems that he might as well be the standard for the gospel. Do his books delve deep into the lore of the gods? If one were to learn about Greek Mythology, would reading Homer alone be sufficient?

I must admit that I read his Odyssey as a teenager, but remember almost nothing of it except the central plot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good sources to introduce people to mythology?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1132/what-are-good-sources-to-introduce-people-to-mythology)

Comment: While it's true some (myself included) consider the last line of the Iliad the saddest passage all of human verse  *(roughly, "And thus was was the funeral of Hector, the breaker of horses.")*, but when we're talking Tragedians, we usually restrict this to the dramatists, Aeschylus, Sophocles and Euripides.

Answer (score 4):

Great question.  Homer is definitely the place to start, but fuller understanding requires the Greek dramatists, [Aeschylus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeschylus), [Sophocles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophocles), and [Euripides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euripides), who were commenting on, and extending, Homer.  *(Euripides, in particular, was quite incisive in his deconstriction of the events surrounding the Trojan War.  The [Trojan Women](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trojan_Women) is still generally considered the greatest anti-war play of all time, without any notable successor until Brecht's [Mother Courage and her Children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother_Courage_and_Her_Children).)*

- In terms of general survey, you probably want to start with:

The [Theogony](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0130) of [Hesiod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hesiod)

The [Bibliotheca](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Apollod.) of [Apollodorus *(aka pseudo-Apollodorus)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollodorus_of_Athens)

The [Metamorphosis](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0028) of [Ovid *(aka P. Ovidius Naso)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovid)

Ovid is especially important in a literary sense per his influence, most notably of Shakespeare.